# Atom text editor installed but I'm not able to find its shortcut in laptop

Tags: atom-editor

I have successfully installed Atom text editor on my laptop but there is no shortcut of it. I have attached the images of installed program. How can I open text editor and how can I create a shortcut of it.
Also when I installed it, it was working fine.
Do I need to install it again?
In which window folder it is installed so that I can create a shortcut of it ?
please check attached images.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to find the install folder( It should most likely be named atom) in either C:/Program Files or C:/Program Files(x86). Navigate inside, find the application right-click-> create shortcut

Answer (score 0):

The default location of Atom IDE is **"C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local\atom"**
There you can search for 'atom.exe', then right click on it and go to share and click on 'Create Desktop Shortcut'. Then rename the shortcut to 'Atom'. Then copy the shortcut file to **"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"** for start menu shortcut.